# How to Factory Reset a Canon Pixma MG3100 Printer?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, router, printer, canon-pixma

I bought a Canon Pixma MG3100 series Wireless Printer+Scanner in around June/July this year. I had been using it since then and everything was great... then I had to change my Wireless Router settings, so had to change settings for this too...

But now it doesn't print anything at all! I connected it to my PC via USB, and changed the settings to static IP address: 10.0.0.22 ... and after that it was active for a while, then again it went inactive. So I opened up my router and added a "reserved ip" to the DHCP settings : 10.0.0.22 (it was already showing a device connected at that IP, but wasn't displaying it's name.) I used the printer's mac address (for reserving the ip) beside the .22 ip address on the router's page. So after this I connected the printer again via usb and set the network settings to "Obtain IP address automatically" and closed.

Now the printer is inactive, on the PC, but active via USB. Also, when I open the url "10.0.0.22" it opens the Printers Network Configuration page... ie, my browser can directly connect to the PC via wifi/lan! But STILL the device is showing inactive for printing.

So I needed to ask how to reset the printer to it's factory settings so that I could re-install the printer on my PC. If not, how to change it's settings to be able to print on home wifi network?

Thanks for any help.

-

Comment: I would just use the software that came with the Canon to reconfigure the network settings on the printer itself.  Be sure you undo any forced configurations on the mac address allow your router to auto configure your network when dealing with a device like this and the problem won't resurface.

Comment: I'm sure the printer's manual sheds some light on doing a factory reset.

Comment: The Printer's manual only has the details on how to plug in the catridges andd basic first time installation. I read somewhere on one of the manuals of a "settings" button for configuration on the printer, but cannot find that manual. It had some info on how to change settings by pressing a button on the printer. Currently I've been using the "Network Settings" on printer's software on windows to configure the settings. ... @Ramhound: You suggest I undo the IP address reservation on netgear router (which is done via mac address)?? Or should I just try and reinstall the printer on my PC?